# Java Event handling and code execution - EventObject

Tags: java, multithreading, events

What happens when a custom `EventListener` handles a custom `EventObject`?

Once the Handler is done:

1. Does the execution go back to the standard thread code? or,
2. Is the thread is closed?

Comment: what is "standard thread code"?

Answer (score 1):

[EventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/EventListener.html) is only Interface (actually very low level) and it only defines what should be implemented. How it is implemented is defined in the class which implements this interface. So, question should be how some particular class handles it. It could be started in separate thread or new thread could be created or current one could be used. Different classes handle it differently. I believe that majority of them just call listener's method in current own thread. That's the reason why it is not advised to do anything long (actually anything at all except few commands to notify about event) inside listener itself. 
That's where flexibility comes - you decide what and when to do. Start new thread and finish it when job done or use existing thread or do your job quickly and hope that current thread doesn't stuck and, for example, GUI window is not frozen.

Answer (score 0):

I create a custom EventListener interface, rather than use the Java standard EventListener interface.  I do this so I can define the method(s).  In this case, I created a handleEvent method that receives a ResultSetEventObject.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

public interface EventListener {

    public void handleEvent(ResultSetEventObject eo);

}
```

So now, let's look at the ResultSetEventObject class.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class ResultSetEventObject extends EventObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6904165475135245131L;

    private ResultSet resultSet;

    public ResultSetEventObject(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        return resultSet;
    }

    public void setResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
        this.resultSet = resultSet;
    }

}
```

This class holds an SQL ResultSet, and has a getter and a setter for the ResultSet.  You can have any variables you want in an EventObject, along with the variable getters and setters.

Finally, lets use the interface in an actual class, ResultSetListenerHandler.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ResultSetListenerHandler {

    private List<EventListener> listeners;

    public ResultSetListenerHandler() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<EventListener>();
    }

    // Add method(s) to generate a ResultSet and perform the
    // fireEvent method.

    public void addListener(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(EventListener listener) {
        for (int i = listeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            if (instance.equals(listener)) {
                listeners.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireEvent(final ResultSet resultSet) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
            final EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ResultSetEventObject eo = new ResultSetEventObject(
                            resultSet);
                    eo.setResultSet(resultSet);
                    instance.handleEvent(eo);
                }

            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    }
}
```

There's a method to add  listeners and a method to remove listeners.

The fireEvent method is the method that actually executes the listener code for each of the listeners.

In this case, I created a separate thread for each of the listeners.  That way, the fireEvent method finishes quickly.  The code in the ResultSetListenerHandler doesn't have to wait for the listener code to finish executing.